# How to pass Java methods dynamically from excel sheet and call those from different java file?

Tags: java

How to pass Java methods dynamically from excel sheet and call those from different java file? Is it possible?
I have the below code, ctrlName and ctrlValue I fetched from excel sheet.
ctrlName = GenericFunctions.fg_wait
ctrlValue = 5

```
public static void callFun(String ctrlName,String ctrlValue) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ctrlName(ctrlValue);
```

In GenericFunctions java fie I have the below:

```
public class GenericFunctions extends GenericFunctionsHelper
{

    public static void fg_wait(int seconds) 
    {
        sleep(seconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use reflection to accomplish this goal.  You'll get exceptions if the method names in your Excel spreadsheet don't match the methods of the class.  You'll also want to catch specific exceptions, I'm just using a generic catch for simplicity:

```
    String methodName = "methodToCall"; // get this from your Excel spreadsheet.
    Integer value = 17; // Get this from your Excel spreadsheet.
    GenericClass classInstance = new GenericClass();

    try {
        Method method = GenericClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Integer.class);
        method.invoke(classInstance, value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle the exception.
    }
```

If you're going down this road, you'll want to examine [the documentation for Java's reflection library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))

Comment: What is the integer value =17 is meant by?? Could you please explain? @RaceYouAnytime

Comment: I have modified my code as below:

`public static void callFun(String ctrlType, String ctrlName,String ctrlValue) {
   String methodName = ctrlName; 
      String value = ctrlValue; 
      GenericFunctions classInstance = new GenericFunctions();
      try {
          Method method =GenericFunctions.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);
          method.invoke(classInstance, value);
      } catch (Exception e) {
       System.err.println( e );
      } }`
I'm getting "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: GenericFunctions.fg_wait(java.lang.String)" Error..Please assist

Comment: @GopinathRavi are you sure that method exists on GenericFunctions, and takes a String as input?

Comment: @GopinathRavi in your example method on your question, the method takes an int as input, so you might want to change it to String and parse it to an int in the method

Comment: This is what I have it in GenericFuntions class file:
`public class GenericFunctions extends GenericFunctionsHelper
{ 
 public void fg_wait(int seconds) 
 {
  sleep(seconds);
 }

}`
In callFun,I made ctrlValue as String since it is variable i will be getting it from excel and it will be integer in the excel. so I parse it as an int in the GenericFunctions as above. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: @GopinathRavi you specify the method input in the method getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);   I used String.class assuming the method being invoked would take a string input.  So in your case if fg_wait takes an integer, you should specify that when you call getDeclaredMethod(methodName, **Integer.class**);

Comment: After passing the correct arguments, it worked.. Thanks @RaceYouAnytime